# Error regarding using core service in SDL Web 8

Tags: core-service

Recently I made a console application to connect to core service in SDL Web 8. However, the execution of the client program came out an **EndpointNotFoundException**. There were no endpoints listening to receive messages. I checked that the web.config under webRoot  is same as CoreService.Client.dll.config. It's also the same as App.config of my console application.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- Default/example WCF settings for Core Service. These settings should be copied into the host application's configuration file. -->
    <bindings>



 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="Basic" -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamDownload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="Basic" -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>


    </bindings>
    <client>
<endpoint name="basicHttp_201501" address="http://ServerAddress/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService" />
      <endpoint name="streamDownload_basicHttp_201501" address="http://ServerAddress/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/streamDownload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamDownload_basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamDownload" />
      <endpoint name="streamUpload_basicHttp_201501" address="http://ServerAddress/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamUpload_basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamUpload" />
      <!-- endpoint name="batch_basicHttp_201501" address="http://ServerAddress/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/batch_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreServiceBatch" /-->

    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Should I start some service on server side? Or I have missed some configuration?
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message and the code ypu use to instantiate Core Service Client?